# How to 'git blame' on the remote-side repository?

Tags: git, blame

on my server I host my personal git remote-side projects (with gitosis), and I have built a web interface to browse the repositories (something like Github).

On the remote-side, you are not allowed to do a lot of stuff, because a working tree is missing, and this is correct: btw, for a repository explorer, with few commands I can do almost everything.

Except for **git blame**.

I'm not able to find out how to blame a file without a working tree, within the remote-side repository. Got you some ideas?

Comment: Any reason you can't just make a clone with a work tree? Also, doesn't gitweb have a blame view? (I forget how it's implemented.)

Comment: what is remote-side in git? If you wrote a webapp to git, it can still see the full repo on the server.

Comment: Gitweb's (gitweb is git web interface in Perl) 'blame' view works without working area, even in bare repositories.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following should work even in bare repositories:

```
git blame <rev> -- <path>
```

E.g.

```
git blame master -- README.txt
```

Comment: I'm not able to find where the git docs talk about `--` option, by the way this works greatly, tnx

Comment: The `--` option (or separator) is listed in the synopsis of `git help blame`. It's better explained by `git help log`: `To prevent confusion with options and branch names, paths may need to be prefixed with "-- " to separate them from options or refnames`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to find where the git docs talk about -- option, by the way this works greatly

Actually, this is necessary because "`git blame`" is prepared to take an
ancient odd argument order "`blame <path> <rev>`" in addition to the
usual "`blame [<rev>] <path>`".

That means, as Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) will explain "`git blame HEAD COPYING`" in a bare repository failed to run, while "`git blame HEAD -- COPYING`" run just fine.

But from 2.17 on, you won't need '`--`' anymore.

See [commit 0c668f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c668f559cc149720b999d7bd1c0060e9fd7caf3) (05 Feb 2018) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0c668f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c668f559cc149720b999d7bd1c0060e9fd7caf3), 07 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `blame`: tighten command line parser

> An ancient odd argument order "`blame <path> <rev>`" in addition to the
> usual "`blame [<rev>] <path>`" has at least two negative
> ramifications:
>
> - In order to tell these two apart, it checks if the last command
>   line argument names a path in the working tree, using
>   `file_exists()`.
>   However, "`blame <rev> <path>`" is a request to
>   explain each and every line in the contents of `<path>` stored in
>   revision `<rev>` and does not need to have a working tree version
>   of the file.  A check with `file_exists()` is simply wrong.
> - To coerce that mistaken `file_exists()` check to work, the code
>   calls `setup_work_tree()` before doing so, because the path it has
>   is relative to the top-level of the project tree.
>   However, "`blame <rev> <path>`" MUST be usable even in a bare repository,
>   and there is no reason for letting `setup_work_tree()` complain
>   and die with "This operation must be run in a work tree".
>
> To correct the former, switch to check if the last token is a
> revision (and if so, parse arguments using "`blame <path> <rev>`"
> rule).
>
> Correct the latter by getting rid of `setup_work_tree()` and
> `file_exists()` check--the only case the call to this function matters
> is when we are running "`blame <path>`" (i.e. no starting revision and
> asking to blame the working tree file at `<path>`, digging through the
> `HEAD` revision), but there is a call in `setup_scoreboard()` just
> before it calls `fake_working_tree_commit()`.

So in short, starting Git 2.17, this will work in a bare repo:

```
git blame master -- README.txt
```

---

And with Git 2.22, the error message "`This operation must be run in a work tree`" should disappear!

"`git blame -- path`" in a non-bare repository starts blaming from the working tree, and the same command in a bare repository errors out because there is no working tree by definition.
The command has been taught to instead start blaming from the commit at HEAD,
which is more useful.

See [commit a544fb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a544fb08f8bfa3a9a566d436e5e81dd30fb21c4c) (07 Apr 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8620d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8620d3ca7a01c1108f3145cc77dbda6e0e970c6), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `blame`: default to HEAD in a bare repo when no start commit is given

> When '`git blame`' is invoked without specifying the commit to start
> blaming from, it starts from the given file's state in the work tree.
> However, when invoked in a bare repository without a start commit,
> then there is no work tree state to start from, and it dies with the
> following error message:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
>   true
> $ git blame file.c
>   fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
> ```
>
> This is misleading, because it implies that '`git blame`' doesn't work
> in bare repositories at all, but it does, in fact, work just fine when
> it is given a commit to start from.
>
> We could improve the error message, of course, but let's just default to HEAD in a bare repository instead, as most likely that is what the user wanted anyway (if they wanted to start from an other commit, then they would have specified that in the first place).
>
> '`git annotate`' is just a thin wrapper around '`git blame`', so in the
> same situation it printed the same misleading error message, and this
> patch fixes it, too.

---

Note: if you are using gitweb to see the "blames", as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169556/how-to-git-blame-on-the-remote-side-repository#comment4506305_4169556) by [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski), there is a rather old bug in gitweb, where the incremental blame output in javascript actions mode never worked.
This is fixed with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019).

See [commit 52bd3e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52bd3e46574baecf06562d4da857ba445981beb9) (27 Oct 2019) by [Robert Luberda (`roblub`)](https://github.com/roblub).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0d6799e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d6799e563de1814edd4f659e4aea94b1dfba55b), 30 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`gitweb`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52bd3e46574baecf06562d4da857ba445981beb9): correctly store previous rev in javascript-actions mode
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Robert Luberda</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jakub Narębski</sup>

> Without this change, the setting
>
> ```
> $feature{'javascript-actions'}{'default'} = [2];
> ```
>
> in `gitweb.conf` breaks gitweb's blame page: **clicking on line numbers displayed in the second column on the page has no effect**.
>
> For comparison, with javascript-actions disabled, clicking on line numbers loads the previous version of the line.
>
> Addresses https://bugs.debian.org/741883.

---

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "[`git blame --contents=file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f4a7c24c094cff87a4b5a02550b321591d847ca0/Documentation/git-blame.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---contentsltfilegt))</sup> has been taught to work in a bare repository.

See [commit 835950b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/835950bd19260426f664a9b0164c580db9f9aacb) (21 Jul 2023) by [Han Young (`eseedo`)](https://github.com/eseedo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4a7c24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4a7c24c094cff87a4b5a02550b321591d847ca0), 04 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`blame`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/835950bd19260426f664a9b0164c580db9f9aacb): allow `--contents` to work with bare repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han Young</sup>

> The `--contents` option can be used with [`git blame`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/835950bd19260426f664a9b0164c580db9f9aacb/Documentation/git-blame.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame))</sup> to blame the file as if it had the contents from the specified file.
> Since [1a3119e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a3119ed06c8fbb1c00a6aa3615299252575abab) ("`blame`: allow `--contents` to work with non-HEAD commit", 2023-03-24, Git v2.41.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62df03c277c1f419fdf25321464e62a0b6c74025) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae73b2c8f1da39c39335ee76a0f95857712c22a7)), the `--contents` option can work with non-HEAD commit.
> However, if you try to use `--contents` in a bare repository, you get the following error:
>
> ```
> fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
> ```
>
> This is because before trying to generate a fake working tree commit, we always call `setup_work_tree()`.
> But in a bare repo, working tree is not available.
> The call to `setup_work_tree` is used to prepare the reading of the blamed file in the working tree, which isn't necessary if we are reading the contents from the specific file instead of the file in the working tree.
>
> Add a check in `setup_scoreboard` to skip `setup_work_tree` if we are reading from the file specified in `--contents`.
>
> This enables us to use `--contents` in a bare repo.
> This is a nice addition on top of [1a3119e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a3119ed06c8fbb1c00a6aa3615299252575abab), having a working tree to use `--contents` is optional.
>
> Add test for the `--contents` option with bare repo to the annotate-tests.sh test script.