# Error with Git server repository and work tree

Tags: git, version-control

i have a little problem with a git server repository. On every command line input i got the following error:

> fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

On example i get this error on `ls -la` or `mkdir`.

I initialized this repo with `git init --bare` and i have this problem on one server and i don't know why. The server runs on Debian Squeeze.

Here the repo config file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You're in a *bare* repository so many of the commands are not available or require special flags. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11377827/440302

Comment: the problem is on other machines i have no errors and i don't understand why.

Comment: Do you have a [custom shell prompt](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt)?

Comment: i have on all machines oh-my-zsh i think this isn't the Problem

Comment: You said it affects *all commands* (i.e. even non-git ones)?  Does it occur in another shell?

Comment: I think the problem is the agnoster theme from oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Agnoster's theme has a custom prompt designed for Git, so chances are that it fails to realize it's a bare repository and attempts to use Git commands on it.  (The curious part is why it seems to work on your other computers.)  Perhaps you should report this as a bug?

Comment: Yes its curious. I openend a issue in github for this bug, problem whatever. I think this is the combination of system, git and oh-my-zsh that throws this error. On all other machines runs debian 7