# Search Git remote branches for commit where file contents were added?

Tags: git, github

How can I search all of my Git remote branches for the commit where a specific line or two of code were added (not just a file, but contents within them)?

My repos are all on github.

Comment: Please explain downvotes, this is an honest question that I am struggling with!

Comment: What have you tied?  You need to demonstrate that you have attempted to figure out the question on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [`git blame`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) suit your needs? You can run it on a specific revision (irrelevant to whether it's on the remote or not, see [How to 'git blame' on the remote-side repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169556/how-to-git-blame-on-the-remote-side-repository)).

For example:

```
$ git blame master file_in_question.c
$ git blame 20f89e16 file_in_question.c
```

---

Also, if your repositories are on GitHub, you can use their interface to `git blame` if you'd prefer. See ["Using git blame to trace changes in a file"](https://help.github.com/articles/using-git-blame-to-trace-changes-in-a-file)

Comment: It might, but I need to check for specific contents of a file.

How would I search through all commits, in all remote branches, looking for the point when a specific line of code was added?

Comment: That's precisely what `git blame` does (see [Using git blame to trace changes in a file](https://help.github.com/articles/using-git-blame-to-trace-changes-in-a-file)). Just run `git blame <branch> <file>` for each non-merged branch (with merged branches, just take the more recent, `git blame` will navigate the whole history).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `git blame`, you can also search in local branches with

```
git log -S<search-string> --source --all
```

It may search your local remote-tracking branches too, but I'm not sure. You could always just make a local branch of your remote ones, of course. See [git: finding a commit that introduced a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/git-finding-a-commit-that-introduced-a-string/5816177#5816177) for more details.

There's also a regex version that you could use (see [`git log` docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)):

> ```
> -G<regex>
> ```
>
> Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given `<regex>`.