# What is the fastest way to find out who commited a particular segment of code when using Git?

Tags: git

What is the fastest way to find out who commited a particular segment of code when using Git?

Comment: That would probably be [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does git blame do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203001/what-does-git-blame-do)

Comment: Yes, if he knew git blame is what he was looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git blame <filename>`. You will be shown the name of the author, timetag and commit of each code fragment of the file.

This is the syntax you would find on git blame's man page:

```
usage: git blame [<options>] [<rev-opts>] [<rev>] [--] <file>

<rev-opts> are documented in git-rev-list(1)

--incremental         Show blame entries as we find them, incrementally
-b                    Show blank SHA-1 for boundary commits (Default: off)
--root                Do not treat root commits as boundaries (Default: off)
--show-stats          Show work cost statistics
--progress            Force progress reporting
--score-debug         Show output score for blame entries
-f, --show-name       Show original filename (Default: auto)
-n, --show-number     Show original linenumber (Default: off)
-p, --porcelain       Show in a format designed for machine consumption
--line-porcelain      Show porcelain format with per-line commit information
-c                    Use the same output mode as git-annotate (Default: off)
-t                    Show raw timestamp (Default: off)
-l                    Show long commit SHA1 (Default: off)
-s                    Suppress author name and timestamp (Default: off)
-e, --show-email      Show author email instead of name (Default: off)
-w                    Ignore whitespace differences
--indent-heuristic    Use an experimental indent-based heuristic to improve diffs
--compaction-heuristic
                      Use an experimental blank-line-based heuristic to improve diffs
--minimal             Spend extra cycles to find better match
-S <file>             Use revisions from <file> instead of calling git-rev-list
--contents <file>     Use <file>'s contents as the final image
-C[<score>]           Find line copies within and across files
-M[<score>]           Find line movements within and across files
-L <n,m>              Process only line range n,m, counting from 1
--abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s
```