# Is there an easy way to see the developers involved in a merge conflict?

Tags: git

As branch manager, when merging branches, often there are merge conflicts. Is there any way of getting the names of the developers involved in the conflicts as they are not necessarily me?

Comment: You are looking for [git blame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203001/what-does-git-blame-do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The tool you are looking for is [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame):

> Annotates each line in the given file with information from the
>   revision which last modified the line. Optionally, start annotating
>   from the given revision.

This should solve your issue.

Comment: And the funny thing is I knew about this command already lol. Works great for merge conflicts also.

Comment: @ericcurtin, if this answers your question, please would you be so kind to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it? I'm available for further details, if needed.